# Django url showed error: unresolved reference

Tags: python, django

I have a url path in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
...
```

]

but the url will show: unresolved reference 'url'. Did I miss something to import?

Comment: Is the problem solved? If so please choose an answer to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Django 2 `url()` was replaced with `path()` and `re_path()`. If you are not using Django 1, you can update your code to use `path()`.

```py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

For matching a path with RegEx like the Django 1 `url()` function you can use `re_path()` like this...

```py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

However, because of how simple the path you are trying to match is, I would recommend using `path()`. It saves to overhead of performing a regular expression match. Use `path()` over `re_path()` as much as possible.

You can read more on the official Django documentation. See links below.

[Django 3 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)

[Old Django 1 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

You may be using **Django 2.x**

For [django-1.x](/questions/tagged/django-1.x), you can not use such `path(..)`s, and in that case you need to **write a regular expression**, like:

```
    url(r'^complete/(?P<todo_id>[0-9]+)$', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

If you are using [django-2.x](/questions/tagged/django-2.x), you probably want to use **`path(..)`**, like you have.

I believe it may be to do with how you've set up your regex.

For urls, instead of this:

`url('complete/<todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),`

try this:

```
url(r'^complete/(?P<todo_id>\d+)$', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

Or incase you want to use [`path`]

```
path('complete/<int:todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```